# Google Analytics goals event on phone number click not working

Tags: google-analytics

I'm having issues setting up an event as a goal when you click the phone number in the header of my site.

This is what I have in the navigation bar:

```
<a href="tel:012345678" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'telephone', eventAction: 'click', eventLabel: '012345678'});">
<span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
<i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i>                      </span>
<span class="elementor-icon-list-text">012345678</span>
</a>
```

In my Google Analytics goals settings, I got:

**Name:** Call Main Number

**Type:** event

### Goal Details

**Category (Equals To):** telephone

**Action (Equals To):** click

**Label:** Null

**Value:** Null

I'm seeing the actions preformed in Behavior -> Events -> overview but not conversions.

The issue I'm seeing is when I go to Conversions (under reports) and click goals (overview), I see Call Main Number (Goal 7 Completions) but it doesn't count up. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ga()` then you should be using the [analytics.js documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events). NOT gtag.js documentation.

For analytics.js your code should look like:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event','telephone', 'click', '012345678')"
```